# Name or Service not known in Kubernetes pod causing the pod to crash

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on the Azure environment where I have private cluster enabled . I am getting issue related to the "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known" . This is causing my pod in kubernetes cluster to fail .I checked the configuration and found that all my event hubs are available and are accessible to all the networks . Please let me know how can I resolve this error .

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.CreateConnectionAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender.CreateLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender.OnSendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpEventDataSender.OnSendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventDataSender.SendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas, String partitionKey)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.PartitionSender.SendAsync(IEnumerable`1 eventDatas)
   at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.PartitionSender.SendAsync(EventDataBatch eventDataBatch)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<<ImplementationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.Wrap.AsyncPolicyWrapEngine.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<ImplementationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<<ImplementationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
   at Polly.Wrap.AsyncPolicyWrapEngine.ImplementationAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext, IAsyncPolicy outerPolicy, IAsyncPolicy innerPolicy)
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)
```

Comment: Did you tried by creating temp pod and then curl the endpoints? If that is not working, then most probably its issue around kube-dns deployment, check its logs.

Comment: As I am new to this , Is it possible to provide the links that I can refer please

Comment: Try following https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ & https://www.cloud-architect.fr/2021/04/22/dns-resolution-problems-in-aks/

Comment: I checked the DNS server settings and it is fine . We are able to get the corresponding pods related to it when we ran the command . Is there any other way to fix this or any other probable cause of failure ?